# How to replace echo command with print command?

Tags: command-line

I am tying to print a line " hello Everyone"
Using echo I can print it like echo "hello Everyone"
But when I replace echo with print like print " hello Everyone"
I get error message.

Here's my prompt

```
niraj@niraj-VPCEB4L1E:~/Religion$ echo "hello world"
hello world
niraj@niraj-VPCEB4L1E:~/Religion$ print "hello world"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "hello world" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "hello world"
niraj@niraj-VPCEB4L1E:~/Religion$ ^C
```

Comment: I just did I am a starter with ubuntu and I was trying to just replace echo with print command. I just wanna know can we replace echo with print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `print` from bash, but `printf`:

```
$ print "Hello"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "Hello" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "Hello"
$ printf "Hello\n"
Hello
```

`print` is an symbolic link to `run-mailcap`:

```
$ type print
print is hashed (/usr/bin/print)
$ ls -l /usr/bin/print
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 sep 18 14:02 /usr/bin/print -> run-mailcap
```

> run-mailcap,  view,  see,  edit,  compose, print - execute programs via entries in the mailcap file
>
> The see, edit, compose and **print** versions are just aliases that default
>          to the view, edit, compose, and **print** actions (respectively).

That's why you get errors.